# SQL Server Script for Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

i don't know much SQL server, and need a script to generate the table for a form, i know how to do this in mySQL but no idea in SQL Server.

This is the data from my form:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
    <form id="form" action="process.php">
        <div id="formTop" class="formTop">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required /><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required /><br>
            <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" required /><br>
        </div>
        <div id="formBottom" class="formBottom">
            <textarea type="text" name="lema" id="lema" rows="7" required></textarea>
            <input type="image" id="formSend" src="img/btConcursar.png" class="image-responsive">
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function IsEmail(email) {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            return regex.test(email);
        }
        //$("#form").submit(function (event) {
        $("#formSend").click(function () {
            /* stop form from submitting normally */

            if ($('#nombre').val().trim() == "") {
                //alert("please enter name");
            }
            else if ($('#email').val().trim() == "") {
                //alert("please enter email");
            }
            else if (!IsEmail($('#email').val().trim())) {
                //alert("please enter valid email");
            }
            else if ($('#lema').val().trim() == "") {
                //alert("please enter message");
            }
            else if ($('#telefono').val().trim() == "") {
                //alert("please enter phone number");
            }
            else {
                var url = window.location.pathname + "/" + "InsertForm";
                var succeededAjaxFn = function (result) {
                    alert("successfully submitted");
                    $('#fbshare').show();
                    $('#formbg').hide();
                };
                var failedAjaxFn = function (result) {
                    //alert("failed to submit" + result);
                    alert("");
                };
                var paramList = '{' + '"name":' + '"' + $('#nombre').val() + '",' + '"email":' + '"' + $('#email').val() + '",' + '"message":' + '"' + $('#lema').val() + '",' + '"phoneNumber":' + '"' + $('#telefono').val() + '"}';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: paramList,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: succeededAjaxFn,
                    error: failedAjaxFn
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

So i need the table for: `nombre` `email` `telefono` and `lema`

I will really appreciate any help that you can give me with this.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a table using SQL Server that has four columns (`nombre`, `email`, `telefono`, and `lema`)? If so, you might look up something like http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/tables/create_table.php for the syntax. The code you provided is just markup and front-end scripting, but any detail you can provide about the server/back-end scripting would be much more useful to anyone trying to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, i think that the link that you provided me and the answer i got from ProblemSolver, is the key. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
Nombre varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Telefono varchar(15) NOT NULL,
Lema varchar(max)
)
```

where NOT NULL forces an entry to have some value in those fields. From there you will probably want a primary key, which you can include in the type specification i.e. changing to

`Nombre varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY`